# Java Box program with multiple methods and constructors

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am a beginner in programming and am having trouble with using constructors, specifically. I have to write a program for one of my labs that must consist only of:

> 1. Three instance variables – length, width and height (each of type double)
>
>    2. One instance variables – input (type Scanner) initialized to System.in
>    3. Default constructor (no-arg) – initialize all three instance variables to 1
>    4. Initial constructor – initialize all three instance variables
>    5. Copy constructor – copy Box
>    6. inputWidth, inputLength, and inputHeight methods that set the instance variables based on user input have not parameters and do not
>         return a value.
>    7. a displayDimensions method that displays the length X Width X height (separated by “X”) and does not return a value.
>    8. a calcVolume method that has no parameters and calculates the volume of the box
>
> We also were given application BoxTest in which the output must
>   exactly match the following:
>
> - Default dimensions are 1.0 X 1.0 X 1.0 with volume of 1.0
> - Initial dimensions are 8.5 X 11.0 X 1.0 with volume of 93.5
> - Copied dimensions are 8.5 X 11.0 X 1.0 with volume of 93.5
> - Update dimensions
> - Enter length: 1
> - Enter width: 2
> - Enter height: 3
> - Updated dimensions are 1.0 X 2.0 X 3.0 with volume of 6.0

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Box {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double length, width, height;

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

new Box() {     //  

Box defaultBox=new Box();
    double length = 1.0;
    double width = 1.0;
    double height = 1.0;
    System.out.print("Default dimensions are " + length + " X " + width + " X " + height);
    defaultBox.displayDimensions();
    System.out.println(" with volume of "+defaultBox.calcVolume());

Box initialBox=new Box(length, width, height);
    length = 8.5;
    width = 11.0;
    height = 1.0;
    System.out.print("Initial dimensions are " + length + " X " + width + " X " + height);
    initialBox.displayDimensions();
    System.out.println(" with volume of "+initialBox.calcVolume());

Box copyBox=new Box(initialBox);
    System.out.print("Copied dimensions are " + length + " X " + width + " X " + height);
    copyBox.displayDimensions();
    System.out.println(" with volume of "+copyBox.calcVolume());

    System.out.println("\nUpdate dimensions");
    initialBox.inputLength();
    initialBox.inputWidth();
    initialBox.inputHeight();
    System.out.print("Updated dimensions are ");
    initialBox.displayDimensions();
    System.out.println(" with volume of "+initialBox.calcVolume());
}
double inputLength() {
    Scanner input;
    double length = input.nextDouble(); 
    }
double inputWidth() {
    Scanner input;
    double width = input.nextDouble();
    }
double inputHeight() {
    Scanner input;
    double height = input.nextDouble();
    }

double displayDimensions(double length, double width, double height) {   
    Scanner input;
    }

double calcVolume() {
}

}
```

What am I missing? My program will not compile and gives the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete MethodHeaderName
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete MethodDeclaration
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
at Box.main(Box.java:18)
```

Comment: You have put everything in `main`. Don't do that. As it is, your `Box` class is basically empty, and you are currently *almost* creating an anonymous sub-class in `main`.

Comment: You are missing several closing braces. You need one after the declaration of Independence and one after the Box constructor

Comment: If I add a closing brace right after my Box constructor, it gives me the warning that my length/width/height variables are duplicates. I also added another curly brace at the end for the main and it told me to delete the } token. Also where should I put my main method if not at the beginning? Thanks in advance I thought I had finally grasped these concepts and now I'm getting super frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you have put everything in `main`. Don't do that. As it is, your `Box` class is basically empty, and you are currently almost creating an anonymous sub-class in `main`. Your directions do not mention a `main`, but are pretty straight forward. You were supposed to write something like

```
public class Box {
    // Three instance variables – length, width and height (each of type double)
    private double length, width, height;
    // One instance variables – input (type Scanner) initialized to System.in
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Default constructor (no-arg) – initialize all three instance variables to 1
    public Box() {
        this.length = this.width = this.height = 1;
    }

    // Initial constructor – initialize all three instance variables
    public Box(double length, double width, double height) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    // Copy constructor – copy Box
    public Box(Box b) {
        this(b.length, b.width, b.height);
    }

    // inputWidth, inputLength, and inputHeight methods that set the instance
    // variables based on user input have not parameters and do not return a value.
    public void inputWidth() {
        this.width = input.nextDouble();
    }

    public void inputLength() {
        this.length = input.nextDouble();
    }

    public void inputHeight() {
        this.height = input.nextDouble();
    }

    // a displayDimensions method that displays the length X Width X height
    // (separated by “X”) and does not return a value.
    public void displayDimensions() {
        System.out.printf("%.2fX%.2fX%.2f%n", length, width, height);
    }

    // a calcVolume method that has no parameters and calculates the volume of the
    // box
    public double calcVolume() {
        return length * width * height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This makes sense to me but I made the adjustments and is still not compiling... I think I have to figure out how to call the BoxTest class into my Box class. But when I do that, it gives me the error message "Error: Could not find or load main class BoxTest.BoxTest"

Comment: *I think I have to figure out how to call the BoxTest class into my Box class.* Why do you think that? You have to **run** the provided `BoxTest`. At least you said it was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java class named Package that contains the following:
Package should have three private instance variables of type double named length, width, and height.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).